# What does nginx's %hostdir% mean?

Tags: nginx

In one nginx sample configuration there was such block:

```
    location / {
        root       "%hostdir%";
        index      index.php index.html index.htm;
    }
```

While I understand what it means I couldn't find in nginx documention what exactly `%hostdir%` is and what are other such replacements.

Comment: Probably not something nginx specific but an indication / variable which should be  substituted with a real directory path when that particular sample gets deployed

Comment: This is not nginx’s syntax. Probably some  templating tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%hostdir%` is not an nginx configuration. These are template values filled in by [Open Server](https://ospanel.io/), a Russian-language web development suite similar to XAMPP and other such suites. (Questions about Open Server are not on topic here; try asking questions about it on [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/). The site already has a [tag for questions](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openserver) about it.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't use OpenServer and  was just curious what is that!